Retrieve latest Rows in table
Sample data



AIID
NIC
Status
Remarks
ID
AddedBy
ADT




28
9595
ON THE WAY
NO
8
0
2024-06-06 16:02:33


27
9595
ABSENT
NO
8
0
2024-05-20 16:02:33


26
573
VISITED
NO
10
0
2024-05-09 15:31:55


25
573
ON THE WAY
NO
10
0
2024-05-05 13:17:52


24
573
ABSENT
NO
10
0
2024-05-05 13:17:31


23
9595
VISITED
NO
8
0
2024-05-04 15:50:40


22
9595
ON THE WAY
NO
8
0
2024-05-04 15:50:25


21
1999
VISITED
NO
7
0
2024-05-03 19:29:26


20
1999
ON THE WAY
NO
7
0
2024-05-03 19:29:11



I want to get last updated status in this table..
what I want :



NIC
STATUS
ADT




9595
ON THE WAY
2024-06-06 16:02:33


573
VISITED
2024-05-09 15:31:55


1999
VISITED
2024-05-03 19:29:26



WHAT I TRIED
SELECT
  u1.NIC,
  u1.Status,
  u1.Remarks,
  u1.ADT
FROM callsc2 u1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN callsc2 u2
    ON u1.NIC = u2.NIC
    AND u1.ADT > u2.ADT


Please share your simple data as text not images, so it can be easy for us to help

You were almost there with your query. You just needed to reverse the ADT comparison and add WHERE u2.AIID IS NULL - db<>fiddle. The approach shown by SelVazi should still be the more efficient method, especially with an index on (NIC, ADT).

This can be done by joining your table with a dataset containing max ADT per status :
SELECT u.*
FROM callsc2 u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT NIC, MAX(ADT) AS MAX_ADT
  FROM callsc2 
  GROUP BY NIC
) AS s on s.NIC = u.NIC AND s.MAX_ADT = u.ADT

